# Calculation of Tocken price (for example SOL-USDC)

Tags: solana-program, raydium

Fetched data from a raydium pool.
Which values do I need for the calculation of the "fair price" or rather current price?

```
Outcome should looks something like this : 1 SOL = 169.3 USDC

(If the format or the way the question is asked please give me feedback!)

Updated this question!

import { Connection, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4 } from "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk";

const SOL_USDC_POOL_ID = "58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2"; // Your pool ID

async function getTokenBalance(connection: Connection, vault: PublicKey, decimals: number): Promise<number> {
  const balance = await connection.getTokenAccountBalance(vault);
  return parseFloat(balance.value.amount) / Math.pow(10, decimals); // Adjust the balance for the token's decimals
}

async function parsePoolInfo() {
  const connection = new Connection("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", "confirmed");
  
  const info = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(SOL_USDC_POOL_ID));
  if (!info) return;
  
  // Assuming the structure was successfully decoded
  const poolState = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(info.data);
  
  // Directly use the specific decimals for SOL and USDC
  const baseTokenDecimals = 9; // Decimals for SOL
  const quoteTokenDecimals = 6; // Decimals for USDC
  
  const baseTokenBalance = await getTokenBalance(connection, poolState.baseVault, baseTokenDecimals);
  const quoteTokenBalance = await getTokenBalance(connection, poolState.quoteVault, quoteTokenDecimals);
  
  // The calculation remains the same, but the clarification is that these decimals are now hardcoded
  const priceOfBaseInQuote = quoteTokenBalance / baseTokenBalance;
  
  console.log("Decoded Pool Data:", poolState);
  console.log(`Price of 1 SOL in USDC: ${priceOfBaseInQuote.toFixed(4)}`); // Adjusted for decimals
}

parsePoolInfo();
```

Comment: Could you format your post and give more info? There's not really a way we can answer this in the current form

Comment: Hey @JacobCreech I now tried to format it a little better. So. More info:

I got this information from a pool of the raydium program. The information I got is the data shown in the question.

I tried to calculate the current price based on:
qote total / base total
I also watched for the right decimal usage. 6, 9
But somehow I don´t get the right price... 
Which values do I need to add to the equation?

Answer (score 0):

solved myself.

Answer: I took the AMM but Raydium uses the CLMM.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?